# how to convert strings/lists from a file to integers

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I have a file containing 1000 integers each printed as a new line in the file.
I want to convert these to integers so that I can sort them in ascending order. I've tried it a few different ways but it's not working:

```
    text_file = open("integers.txt", "r")
    new_list = (text_file.read())
    print(new_list)
    for i in range(new_list):
        new_list.append(int(new_list[i]))
```

Error message:
for i in range(new_list):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I also tried it with readlines.

```
    text_file = open("integers.txt", "r")
    new_list = (text_file.readlines())
    print(new_list)
    for i in range(new_list):
        new_list.append(int(new_list[i]))
```

Error message:
   for i in range(new_list):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I also sometimes get the error that '/n' can't be converted to an integer but I don't know how to get rid of the '/n' in the code if each integer in the file is printed on a new line. 
How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a few example lines fom your integers.txt? Is there any text or commas in there?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
with open("integers.txt", "r") as text_file:
    new_list = [int(line) for line in text_file]
```